# Get date value from header

Tags: json, google-sheets, datatables, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to use Google Sheets as a JSON backend. The JSON output is here:

```
           "gsx$company": {  //all is ok
                "$t": "Company name"
            },
            "gsx$_clrrx": {  //might be 12.02.16
                "$t": "132"
            },
            "gsx$_cyevm": {  //might be 17.02.16
                "$t": "142"
            },
            "gsx$_cztg3": {  //...
                "$t": "155"
            }
```

In table header I have a date value. But I can't get the right field name from header. It always returns random name, like this `_cztg3`.

How can I get the date from header?

**Table example**
[image: Table example]

Comment: your question is not clear enough you should give a spreadsheet demo and explain with more details what you are doing and where you want to go

Comment: Can you provide us a JSFiddle ?